# use of the comma-operator in a tested expression causes the left argument to be ignored when it has no side-effects

Tags: visual-c++

I got that warning when I defined 2 conditions for a `for` loop in C++. Here is the code

```
int a;
cin >> a;
int n;
cin >> n;
int b = pow(10, a - 1), c = pow(10, a - 1) * 1.2;
for (int i = b; i < c, i <= n; i++)
     //do sth
```

Does anybody know what is this warning about?

Answer (score 1):

Expression with comma operator returns value of the second part ( `i <= n` in your case ). Value of the first part is ignored.
Read here about comma operator:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator

Use `i < c && i <= n` if you want both conditions to be true (or other operators depending on your task).